# Why is my popup not showing, when by default it should?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet for a project I'm working on, and on [their quickstart guide](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-setup/) there is a popup. However, in my example the popup won't show up, and I'm having trouble understanding why. This is my code (I put it all to include dependencies):

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchCoordinates } from "../../redux/slices/coordinates.slice";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.webpack.css";
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility";

import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

import MarkerClusterGroup from "react-leaflet-markercluster";

const Map = () => {
  const coordinates = useSelector((state) => state.coordinates.coordinates)[0]; // coordinates come from Redux slice, refer to Redux folder
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.loading);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const initFetch = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCoordinates());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    initFetch();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      setPosition([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);
    });
  }, [initFetch]);

  const [position, setPosition] = useState([]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <div>I'm loading</div>
  ) : (
    position[0] != null && position[1] != null && (
      <MapContainer style={{ height: "100vh" }} center={position} zoom={13}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}"
          accessToken={process.env.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
          id="mapbox/streets-v11"
        />
        <MarkerClusterGroup>
          {coordinates &&
            coordinates.map((coordinate) => (
              <GeoJSON
                data={coordinate.geolocation}
                key={coordinates.indexOf(coordinate)}
              >
                  <Popup>Hello world!</Popup>
              </GeoJSON>
            ))}
        </MarkerClusterGroup>
      </MapContainer>
    )
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong or what should I try?

Comment: Don't forget to import Popup from react-leaflet. PS : You can find a complete demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gplvzs

Comment: Yes of course, on the example I imported it. I don't think that's the problem, because in these cases it doesn't even get compiled

Comment: GeoJSON contains the Marker component, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does. In fact, what I get out of this code is a fully working map, with markers at the right place; what I don't get is just the possibility to open a popup by clicking on the markers. Because in the end each popup is supposed to show information related to a single point

Comment: Why not put the Popup in your GeoJSON component? In your example, you will have `<GeoJSON data={coordinate.geolocation} key={coordinates.indexOf(coordinate)} />` with a popup="Hello World!" props if needed ... Try to see...

Comment: I tried, didn't work

Comment: I thought GeoJSON was a component you made, but it's actually imported from React-Leaflet (sorry...). Your problem is known and comes from GeoJSON. There are several answers to this problem : using `onEachFeature` https://github.com/CodingWith-Adam/geoJson-map-with-react-leaflet/blob/master/src/components/MyMap.jsx, using `FeatureGroup` instead of GeoJSON https://codesandbox.io/s/e5jvn?file=/src/App.js:132-144 .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683314/react-leaflet-geojson-oneachfeature-popup-with-custom-react-component

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided Giulio, a potential solution could be found after confirming the following possibilities. The reason I say this is because of the giveaway when you say your popup fails to even compile. I assume everything else renders as is.

1. `{coordinates && coordinates.map((coordinate) => ...`, if the popup is not compiling at all. There's a good chance the data represented by coordinates is not present/truthy.
2. `const coordinates = useSelector((state) => state.coordinates.coordinates)[0];`, just a suspicion since I don't see a reference to the contents of your redux store. But I would triple check your are accessing it correctly.
3. Your `coordinates.map` logic is probably executed on a non-iterable object.

Try ruling out the above recommendations and let me know what you think.

*If nothing works yet*,

- Providing snippets of what components are present in your DOM tree via React dev tools
- Showing the JS loaded in your preferred browser's devtools network tab
- Or even what **coordinates** is in the browser. That would greatly narrow down the cause of your bug.

Comment: The second option is definitely not the one, the data from Redux is arriving as it is supposed to, i.e. as an array of GeoJSON objects. That's why I would rule out also option 3, the map logic is done on an array which, until the data is fetched is undefined (hence the `coordinates && ...`). By looking at the Components in the DevTools, doesn't look like the Popup gets rendered at all, which makes option 1 possible; however, coordinates is present, because markers are correctly shown where they are supposed to be shown